# How to estimate the covariance matrix of multivariate Gaussian distribution when the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix are known?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution

Consider $X_1, X_2$,$\dots$, $X_n$, $\overset{i.i.d}{\sim}$ $N_{p}(\pmb{\mu},\pmb{\Sigma})$, where $\pmb{\mu}= (\mu_1,\dots,\mu_p)$ unknown, and $\pmb{\Sigma} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \quad \sigma_{12} \dots \sigma_{1p} \\ \sigma_{12} \quad 1 \dots \sigma_{2p} \\ \dots \\ \sigma_{1p} \quad \sigma_{2p} \dots 1 \end{pmatrix}$, how to compute the MLE of $\pmb{\mu}$ and $\pmb{\Sigma}$?